# mysql condition in a select

Tags: mysql

My table:

```
id | elite | pos
1  |   0   |  9  
2  |   1   |  8
3  |   0   |  7
4  |   1   |  6
5  |   0   |  5
6  |   1   |  4
7  |   0   |  3
8  |   1   |  2
9  |   0   |  1
10 |   1   |  0
```

I have this simple query

```
SELECT id, elite FROM tbl LIMIT 0, 5 ORDER BY pos DESC
```

It will return the `id 1 2 3 4 5`. Over time, these values were to change. The result must have always a count of 5, however if on the result there are at least one `id` with an `elite >= 1`, the result must not contain any more `id` with an `elite` having the `1` value. So the result must not contain `id` having more than one `elite >= 1`.

Is this possible within a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to combine two queries, like so:

```
(SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE elite = 1 LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE elite = 0)
ORDER BY pos DESC LIMIT 5
```

It will give the results you need.
Check out Mysql reference for [UNIONs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Do I really need to do a wildcard (*) on `SELECT`?

Comment: No, you can select whatever columns you wish. They just have to be same for the both selects